# uno de mis condicionales en jsx no funciona estoy usando clases dinámicas

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

lo que pasa es que el segundo condicional con el metodo push no esta ejecutandose por lo que solo tengo la clase red en pantalla dentro del `console.log`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que tengo dentro del render

```js
const classes = [];

    if (this.state.persons.length <= 2) {
      classes.push("red");
      console.log(classes);
    }
    if (this.state.persons.lenght <= 1) {
      classes.push("bold");
      console.log(classes);
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi! I'm a react app.</h1>
        <p className={classes.join(" ")}>this works!</p>
        <button style={style} onClick={this.togglePersonsHandler}>
          Toggle Persons
        </button>
        {persons}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Has escrito mal: `lenght` tiene que ser `length`

Comment: por dios un error de typo XD, lo siento mucho, ahora te voto para arriba, gracias!!

Comment: Cuánto daño ha hecho la palabra length y su hermano width... xD